# What does it mean that I have implemented "finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection"?

Tags: java, android

I have an SQLite database. One of my columns is named `KEY_SWITCH`. I want to convert the integers in this list into an ArrayList and then print it to my console.

Here's my code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllIntegerValues() {
    ArrayList<Integer> yourIntegerValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor result = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] {KEY_SWITCH}, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            yourIntegerValues.add(result.getInt(result
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_SWITCH)));
        } while (result.moveToNext());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(yourIntegerValues.toArray()));
    return yourIntegerValues;
}
```

I run the code like this

```
DBAdapter_Metrics mydbmetric;

private SQLiteDatabase dbmetric;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_metric_list);
    openDBMetrics();
    populateListViewFromDNewBMetric();
    mydbmetric.getAllIntegerValues();
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:
`endAllActiveAnimators on 0x915c1380 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8f550150`

I found the error changes depending on where in my code I launch the `getAllIntegerValues()`

For example, when I created a drop down menu with an option to run it, I got this error

`endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8e3b5300 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x8ef83f50`

I attempted to learn more about this error by running a try/catch thing that looks like this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_metric_list);
    openDBMetrics();
    populateListViewFromDNewBMetric();
    mydbmetric.getAllIntegerValues();

    try { mydbmetric.getAllIntegerValues(); }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This yielded the following message

`....layouts W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection`

## My Question

What does this error mean and why is it preventing me from printing my ArrayList to the console/log?